# Grails 3 InterceptUrlMap, should it work?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying something very simple with Grails 3, and have been having difficulty. I have a controller called WorkOrder. I want to continue to generate scaffolding for it so I have no interest at this point in adding annotations in there for access control (which works). In my application.groovy I have :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    [pattern: '/workOrder/**',               access: ['ROLE_SECRET']]
]
```

Based on what I read in the documentation this should require the role ROLE_SECRET to access anything under /workOrder/. It doesn't seem to work, and not only that, but when I attempt to access /workOrder/index with a user which has this role, I get a 403 with the error

```
Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [securityConfigType](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/requestMappings.html#configGroovyMap) pointed to InterceptUrlMap:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
```